# Either in not both clause in select sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Find the names of all departments located either in BOSTON or in DALLAS" and not in both cities.

I having the code like this

```
SELECT D.DNAME 
FROM DEPARTMENT D 
INNER JOIN DEPTLOC L ON L.DNAME = D.DNAME 
WHERE L.CITY='BOSTON' 
OR L.CITY='DALLAS' ;
```

But this will show the department that located in BOSTON OR DALLAS . But i just want either in, what should i put in order to get the result.

Example:
in my DEPTLOC TABLE

```
     //DEPTLOC
     DNAME      CITY
     ----------------
     ACCOUNTING  BOSTON
     ACCOUNTING  DALLAS
     SALES       DALLAS
     TRANSPORT   BOSTON
     TRANSPORT   DALLAS
```

So in my DEPARTMENT
i should get output like

```
      DNAME
      ----------
      SALES
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group them, then calculate the total count for each departments, then filter all departments which has only one location.

```
SELECT D.DNAME 
FROM DEPARTMENT D 
INNER JOIN DEPTLOC L ON L.DNAME = D.DNAME 
WHERE L.CITY='BOSTON' 
OR L.CITY='DALLAS'
GROUP BY
D.DNAME
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

Comment: What if it has 2 locations but DALLAS and NY?

Comment: It will appear, the question was exactly BOSTON and DALLAS.

Comment: Tested . work perfectly. i still understanding the code ! THANKS YOU PRED

Comment: can i asked that @Minh said. if two location different.
will it appear two times? or still same?

Comment: @user3553846: It still works. He is right. HAVING COUNT(1) = 1 is not affected to other locations. You can add more data and try.

Comment: If you use a filter with multiple cities, they will be processed and all others will be unused. If you do not specify any cities, all records will be used and the query will display all deps with exactly one location.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT D.DNAME 
FROM DEPARTMENT D 
INNER JOIN DEPTLOC L ON L.DNAME = D.DNAME 
GROUP BY D.DNAME
HAVING 1 = SUM(CASE WHEN L.CITY IN ('BOSTON', 'DALLAS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
SELECT department.dname
  FROM department
  JOIN deptloc
    ON department.dname = deptloc.dname
 WHERE deptloc.city IN ('BOSTON', 'DALLAS')
 GROUP
    BY department.dname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT deptloc.city) = 1
;
```

For that matter, since each value in `deptloc.dname` presumably also occurs in `department.name`, you can dispense with the join and just write:

```
SELECT dname
  FROM deptloc
 WHERE city IN ('BOSTON', 'DALLAS')
 GROUP
    BY dname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT city) = 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
--take only those that ara in one city
SELECT DNAME_WITH_COUNT.DNAME FROM
        --count how many times it occurs
        (SELECT DNAME, COUNT(DNAME) CNT FROM
            --your select with both cities
            (SELECT D.DNAME 
            FROM DEPARTMENT D 
            INNER JOIN DEPTLOC L ON L.DNAME = D.DNAME 
            WHERE L.CITY='BOSTON' 
            OR L.CITY='DALLAS'
            ) 
        )DNAME_WITH_COUNT
    WHERE CNT>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join the `department` table with an aggregate query that returns only one location per department:

```
SELECT     d.dname
FROM       department d
INNER JOIN (SELECT   dname
            FROM     deptloc
            WHERE    city IN ('BOSTON', 'DALLAS')
            GROUP BY dname
            HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1) l ON l.dname = d.dname
```